# How not load one specific property (at all, even lazy) in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using Nhibernate 5.2.3 and ASP.NET Core 2.2. I have one entity Cat which has many Kitten. I want set up query like this when I load Cat not to load any Kitten at all.

I've tried to work around with 'Lazy' attribute and LINQ.
Then I tried to use 'ICriteria' and 'Fecth' method to set 'SelectMode.Skip' but it didn't help.
There is my query to DB

```
var cat = _session.CreateCriteria<Cat>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(nameof(Cat.Id), id))
    .Fetch(SelectMode.Skip, nameof(Cat.Kittens))
    .UniqueResult<GH>();
```

There is Classes and their mapping (by Nhibernate.Mapping.Attribute)

```
public class Cat
{
    [Id(Column = "NUM_REC", Type = "Int32", Name = "Id", Generator = "identity")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Bag(Cascade = "all-delete-orphan", Inverse = true, Lazy = CollectionLazy.False)]
    [Key(Column = "NUM_CAT")]
    [OneToMany(ClassType = typeof(Kitten))]
    public virtual IList<Kitten> Kittens { get; set; }
}
public class Kitten
{
    [Id(Column = "NUM_REC", Type = "Int32", Name = "Id", Generator = "identity")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "NAME")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want make like this: Load only 'Id' property of 'Cat' and don't load (lazy, fetch, eager) Kittens collection.

Comment: So you want something that tries to access Kitten get null or an empty collection instead of triggering lazy load. Not sure you can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to use the Criteria API?

I'm not too familiar with this attribute mapping either, but in order for Lazy loading to work at all the association needs to be bi-directional (I remember seeing this in the documentation but cannot find it). This relationship you need to specify the relationship on both sides, i.e., the kitten object needs a `public virtual Cat Parent { get; set; }` and this property would be mapped `[ManyToOne(Column="NUM_CAT", Lazy="Proxy")]`.

Inverse really only matters for bi-directional associations, otherwise no matter what you specify for `inverse` it will always be `inverse=true` because the other entity knows nothing about the parent and so you are automatically making the parent `Cat` responsible for the association.

Once you add the `Parent` property to the `Cat` object then on the Cat object if `inverse=false` is specified for `Kittens` property then this means the `Cat` is responsible for managing and attributing itself to the `Kitten`. In other words, NHibernate sets the value of `NUM_CAT` during save operations. With `inverse=true`, the `Cat` is not going to manage that association for you and instead any time a `Kitten` is added to a `Cat`, the `Parent` property on `Kitten` needs to be set to the parent instance of `Cat` that is adding `Kitten` to its collection.

Take the following code:

```
var mom = new Cat();
var child1 = new Kitten();
var child2 = new Kitten();

mom.Kittens.Add(child1);
mom.Kittens.Add(child2);

session.Save(mom);
session.Save(child1);
session.Save(child2);
```

With **`inverse=false`:**

```
insert into Cat (NUM_REC) values (1)
insert into Kitten (NUM_REC, NUM_CAT, NAME) values (1, 1, 'Foo')
insert into Kitten (NUM_REC, NUM_CAT, NAME) values (2, 1, 'Foo')
```

With **`inverse=true`:**

```
insert into Cat (NUM_REC) values (1)
--error!, NHibernate has no value for Cat/NUM_CAT
```

So if we set `inverse=false` we need to code this slightly different:

```
var mom = new Cat();
var child1 = new Kitten();
var child2 = new Kitten();

mom.Kittens.Add(child1); child1.Parent = mom;
mom.Kittens.Add(child2); child2.Parent = mom;

session.Save(mom);
session.Save(child1);
session.Save(child2);
```

And we'll get our desired SQL. I generally map this as Kittens being being `inverse=false` and attempt to make the associate managed by the `Cat` still by doing this by wrapping the bag in an Enumerable so outside users cannot add kittens directly to the list and setting the `One-to-Many` `access` as `field.camelCase`. Detailed property definition is found in [5.1.10](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html)

```
public class Cat {
  private IList<Kitten> kittens;
  public virtual IEnumerable Kittens => kittens;
  public virtual void Add(Kitten kitten){
    if (kitten != null){
      kitten.Cat = this;
      this.kittens.Add(kitten);
    }
  }
}
```

To get you're desired behavior ensure you add the bi-directional association to start and:

```
public class Cat {
  [Bag(Cascade="all-delete-orphan", Inverse=true, Lazy=True, Fetch=Select)]
  [Key(Column="NUM_CAT", NotNull="true")]
  [OneToMany(ClassType = typeof(Kitten))]
  public virtual IEnumerable Kittens => kittens;
}
```

Specifying `Fetch=Join` overrides the `Lazy=true`. On you Kitten:

```
public class Kitten {
  [Id(Column="NUM_REC", Type="Int32", Name="Id", Generator="identity")]
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  [Property(Column="NAME")]
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  [ManyToOne(Column="NUM_CAT", Lazy="Proxy")]
  public virtual Cat Parent {get;set;}
}
```

Now you should have access for querying..., when selecting an object by Id just use `session.Get(id)`, if you only need the Id and nothing else use `session.Load(id)` as this will proxy the object and avoid the database unless a property is invoked. If you wanted to do something more complicated just leave out the Kitten...